# Ending a Firebase Query/Callbacks in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to perform a simple query on a Firebase database that gets and returns one object matching the query parameter (in Java)? I'm very new to using Firebase and as far as I can understand the documentation, orderBy() is an asynchronous method that lasts indefinitely, which is why I'm having trouble figuring out how to perform operations on data after the query. Is there some callback notation that allows me to quickly retrieve and return a value and end the query, or am I missing something in the Firebase documentation?

For example, in this method, I want to just figure out if the database contains a specified user and return true if the query matches the user.

```
public void containsUser(String user) {
        DatabaseReference ref = getDatabaseRef("users");
        ref.orderByKey().equalTo("user1").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s){}

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println(databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

To get a single value use addListenerForSingleValueEvent

```
DatabaseReference ref = getDatabaseRef("users");
ref.child("user1").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String value = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();

       // do your stuff here with value

   }

   @Override
   public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

   }
});
```

Comment: Won't this code only respond to a change in the structure/information inside the database? All I'm looking for is a way to retrieve one object and then call some callback function.

Comment: This is proper way of getting one single object from ur database according to the firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query.html#addListenerForSingleValueEvent(com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener)

Comment: And no it will not respond again at any change in the future after it is called once but addValueEventListener does so.